# pandas create new column from a lookup table with row/column names defined by row values in the original dataframe

Tags: pandas, lookup-tables

I have a dataframe (df_table) with two columns, the 'University', and the 'Major'

```
    University  Major
0   UnivA   Business
1   UnivA   Computer
2   UnivC   Computer
3   UnivB   Architecture
```

I also have a lookup table (df_lu), where the row values correspond to 'University' and the column headers
correspond to the Major, with the table entries corresponding to the expected salaries:

```
    University  Business    Computer Architecture
0   UnivA      100          200       300
1   UnivB      150          250       350
2   UnivC      95           86        14
3   UnivD      32           0         27
```

I want to create a new column in the first table, 'Expected_Salary'
with the entries based on the row/column vlaues from the lokup table:

```
    University  Major   Expected_Salary
0   UnivA   Business    100
1   UnivA   Computer    200
2   UnivC   Computer    86
3   UnivB   Architecture    350
```

I have tried something like this:

```
df_table['Salary_Expected'] = df_table['University'].map(df_lu.set_index(
    'University')[col for col in df_lu.column if col==df_table.Major ]
```

but I cannot seem to specify the column properly from the lookup table

Another attempt:

```
df_table['Salary_Expected'] =  df_lu.lookup(df_lu.index.
                                            where(df_lu.University==df_table.University,
```

Again, the specifying of the column name in df_lu seems not to work.
I am hoping there is a straightforward solution, otherwise I can just do a nested loop

Comment: It would be nice to have the code to generate the dataframes you use directly; however, I think you should try and `stack` the data in the second dataframe: `df2 = df2.stack()` then you can rename the index level `major` and then have it be a lookup table for you with the appropriate index

Comment: You don't even need to use your original df. With the look up table just do `df.melt(id_vars = 'University')` and you should get what your looking for.